# Name for a state of an automaton that can't be left

Tags: automata

In an automaton, we might have a state that once reached cannot be left.

It is for example for Ø in

[image: Automaton from Wikipedia]

Is there a common/official name for such a state ?

Comment: Look out, it’s a trap!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a state is usually called a *sink state* or sometimes a *dead state* or a *zero state*.
"Sink state" seems to be the most largely accepted terminology in the literature.

Answer (score 1):

In the notes we use at my institution, it's called a black hole.

Answer (score 0):

From [Theory and Applications of Models of Computation. 9th Annual Conference](https://books.google.fr/books?id=f0e5BQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA380&ots=HErB_0w5z5&dq=automaton%20sink&pg=PA380#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> A *sink state* in an S-automaton is a state whose all outgoing
>   transitions loop into the state itself.